# Why doesn't jQuery delay cause blinking action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, user-interface, jquery-effects

jQuery newb here. I want to make a button blink(but not hide). I have this code that I would think work but doesn't:

```
$("#refresh-60-sec").addClass("pressed-button")
                        .delay(1000)
                        .removeClass("pressed-button")
                        .delay(1000)
                        .addClass("pressed-button")
                        .delay(100)
                        .removeClass("pressed-button")
                        .delay(100)
                        .addClass("pressed-button");
```

This code just seems to leave the button in the state of the last `addClass`. Why? and/or how can I achieve the same effect? (That is the brief blinking of an element)

Thanks.

Comment: addClass isn't an animation, therefore it doesn't get added to the animation queue. .delay() only delays the animation queue. setTimeout would be more approprate here, that or use a jQuery UI effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Kevin   I would create blinking function with fades (in and out) on an interval, like this:

```
function blink() {
    elem.fadeOut(500, function () {
        elem.fadeIn(500);
    });
}
setInterval(blink, 500);
```

see fiddle for working example, http://jsfiddle.net/tiri/2mkPF/